# Unable to read the "plus-minus" symbol from a file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a text file line by line using fget() in c++ and the "plus-minus" symbols show up as a "?" symbol. 
Does it have anything to do with the encoding. I tried switching to Unicode but the result is worse. Please help

Thanks.
EDIT: 
This is my code:

```
#define AMINOACIDS "ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYV"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int getAmino(char* index, int j_index, int i_index){

    int j = 0;  
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    FILE *file; 
    file = fopen("blosum50.txt", "r");

    if(file == NULL){   
        perror("Error at opening the file!");
    }else{

        while (!feof(file))
        {
            printf("In while:\n");
            if (fgets(buffer , 100 , file) == NULL ){       
                break;
            }

            fputs (buffer , stdout);

            if(j == j_index){
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        fclose (file);
     }
   return 0;
   }
int main(void){
   char *aMatrix = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (21));
    strcpy(aMatrix, AMINOACIDS);
    getAmino(aMatrix, 0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, when I hit Ctrl+S it pops up a message: 
[image]

If I press No, the symbols show up as a "?" symbol: 
[image]

If I press Yes, they show up like this: 
[image]

And this is the content of my file:

5 −2 −1 −2 −1 −1 −1 0 −2 −1 −2 −1 −1 −3 -1 1 −0 −3 −2 0
−2 7 −1 −2 −4 1 0 −3 0 -4 −3 3 −2 −3 −3 −1 −1 −3 −1 −3
−1 −1 7 2 −2 0 0 0 1 −3 −4 0 −2 −4 −2 1 0 −4 −2 −3
−2 −2 2 8 −4 0 2 −1 −1 −4 −4 −1 −4 −5 −1 0 −1 −5 −3 −4
−1 −4 −2 −4 13 −3 −3 −3 −3 −2 −2 −3 −2 −2 −4 −1 −1 −5 −3 −1
−1 1 0 0 −3 7 2 −2 1 −3 −2 2 0 -4 −1 0 −1 −1 −1 −3
−1 0 0 2 −3 2 6 −3 0 −4 −3 1 −2 −3 −1 −1 −1 −3 −2 −3
 0 −3 0 −1 −3 −2 −3 8 −2 −4 −4 −2 −3 −4 −2 0 −2 −3 −3 −4
−2 0 1 −1 −3 1 0 −2 10 −4 −3 0 −1 −1 −2 −1 −2 −3 2 −4
−1 −4 −3 −4 −2 −3 −4 −4 −4 5 2 −3 2 0 −3 −3 −1 −3 −1 4
−2 −3 −4 −4 −2 −2 −3 −4 −3 2 5 −3 3 1 −4 −3 −1 −2 −1 1
−1 3 0 −1 −3 2 1 −2 0 −3 −3 6 −2 −4 −1 0 −1 −3 −2 −3
−1 −2 −2 −4 −2 0 −2 −3 −1 2 3 −2 7 0 −3 −2 −1 −1 0 1
−3 −3 −4 −5 −2 −4 −3 −4 −1 0 1 −4 0 8 −4 −3 −2 1 4 −1
−1 −3 −2 −1 −4 −1 −1 −2 −2 −3 −4 −1 −3 −4 10 −1 −1 −4 −3 −3
1 −1 1 0 −1 0 −1 0 −1 −3 −3 0 −2 −3 −1 5 2 −4 −2 −2
0 −1 0 −1 −1 −1 −1 −2 −2 −1 −1 −1 −1 −2 −1 2 5 −3 −2 0
−3 −3 −4 −5 −5 −1 −3 −3 −3 −3 −2 −3 −1 1 −4 −4 −3 15 2 −3
−2 −1 −2 −3 −3 −1 −2 −3 2 −1 −1 −2 0 4 −3 −2 −2 2 8 −1
0 −3 −3 −4 −1 −3 −3 −4 −4 4 1 −3 1 −1 −3 −2 0 −3 −1 5

Comment: Show us the code, show us the file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "worse".

Comment: What encoding does the file have? And where do you see the `?`? If you try to output it on the console: you probably can't :)

Comment: What do you mean by "show up as"?

Comment: Yes it's definitely something to do with encoding, but without seeing either the file or the code no-one will be able to tell you what the problem is. Need to see the code and the **bytes** in the file. Also remember that the problem may not be that you cannot *read* a plus-minus, it may be that you cannot *write* one properly.

Comment: @Theolodis I think the encoding is Western European(Windows) - Codepage 1252

Answer (score 0):

"Save as Unicode" in Visual Studio saves the file as UTF-8 with a "Byte Order Mark"(U+FEFF) prefix. That's why you see 3 characters before the `5` in your second example.

I'm guessing from the jumble of characters that your "plus minus" is actually ∓ not ± ? Because they appear to be read correctly, just not interpreted correctly. You're passing `fputs` the raw string, and it expects ASCII. Not UTF-8.

[`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can convert to UTF-16, which you can then pass to `WriteConsoleW`. Microsoft C++ makes a proper mess of Unicode output, which is strange because Microsoft Windows natively can do it.

Comment: U+FEFF is BOM for UTF-16, not for UTF-8.

Comment: It looks like you want to say UTF-16 in place of UTF-8.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional and I have only the Unicode(UTF-8 without signature). Nothing's changed.

Comment: @dbasic: the `U+` notation denotes codepoints, independent of their encoding. E.g. "A" = U+0041, and can be saved as `00 41` (UTF16-LE), `41 00` (UTF-16 BE), `41` (UTF-8) or even `00 00 00 41` (UTF32-LE)

Answer (score -1):

plus-minus symbol is not the part of standard ASCII (that is from 0-127, 128-255 is extended ASCII).

Extended ASCII value of plus-minus is 241 in decimal.

Unicode code-point is U+00B1 (that is hexadecimal).

When you are saving file as Unicode, it looks like it is UTF-16 encoding. And in your code what you are trying to read in ASCII mode. That is why output looks like this.

On Windows, it should show character 241 (decimal) as `±`. So, if it is 241 in ASCII, it should look like ±.

So, check the character ASCII value or unicode value of the file using some hex editor. This can give you better picture.

Comment: It's not only about he way they are displayed. This affects the parsing also. I get all kinds of characters and I cannot convert them to int.

Comment: What is the value of that character?

Comment: There's about a million extensions to ASCII, so it really doesn't make sense to talk about **the** extended ASCII. E.g. in UTF-8, 0-127 is still ASCII, but 241 definitely is NOT ±. You are right that ± is `U+00B1`, though.

Comment: @dbasic The characters are those from the second console picture.